# iPhone App: touch event and transfer control to other object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitouch

In my iPhone App I want to play with touch events. Here my requirement is as shown in figure:

[image]

I am creating `Button 2` on the `touch drag Exit` event of `Button 1`. Here is the code

```
 -(IBAction)addView:(id)sender{

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.tag=count;
count++;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouch:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouchCancel:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button.frame=CGRectMake(shape1.frame.origin.x-30,shape1.frame.origin.y-40, 100, 100);

   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgname] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button addSubview:close];
  [baseview addSubview:button];

 }
```

Here I am able to create button 2 successfully but the problem is I am not able to drag and move  the button2 in single touch events means while dragging outside on button 1 it is creating button 2 but to move button 2 i have to take my finger off the screen and on next touch on button 2 i could move the button 2.

My question is, how to create button2 and move it across screen on single touch cycle?

Comment: I think you need to use the `Touch` methods and detect which object you are touching. If it is button2 then you have to start moving it which touchesMoved is called. Lets Play! Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Set button UserInteraction Disable ands use following code..

```
[button2 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
button2.center = location;
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
 }
```

[Sample code for dragging image over the view](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/)

Hope, this will help you